# Bootstrap glyphicon in span with href

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
<a href=''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span></a>
```

That's what I'm getting: http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/fb/13/x6/vqmhk3.jpg

And that's what I want to get:
http://screenshu.com/static/uploads/temporary/p2/fm/al/3o8yvo.jpg

I forgot about something. If I use it outside

```
<div class='col-md-1'>
```

then that's looking cool.

@edit

Problem solved. I just forgot to put it all into

```
<li class='list-group-item'>
```

The code should look like that:

```
<li class='list-group-item'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md8'>
          <a href='./settings'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Sorry for question. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question. If you feel that this question would be helpful to anyone else in future, post your solution as an answer (and then 'accept' it), otherwise you could also just delete it.

Comment: Thanks for a solution. I didn't know it.

Comment: Your solution also works for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved. I just forgot to put it all into

```
<li class='list-group-item'>
```

The code should look like that:

```
<li class='list-group-item'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md8'>
          <a href='./settings'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Just adding note as I needed to wrap the <li> tag in a <ul> parent tag